# IIS return Microsoft Data Access Components error

Tags: iis, mdac

I have a web .net application, it will read an excel file using the Microsoft Access Database Engine. It works fine , but recently it is giving some error. From the log, these 2 points i think are the highlight, which I still could not find a solution. I have tried reinstalling Microsoft Access Database Engine, but not helping. Google for it, but didn't manage to get a hint as well.
One funny thing is whenever it happened, I recycle the app pool on IIS and issue was resolved. But then the issue will come back very quickly. If anyone had come across this, would appreciate any help. Thanks.

1. The .Net Framework Data Providers require Microsoft Data Access Components(MDAC).  Please install Microsoft Data Access Components(MDAC) version 2.6 or later
2. Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {2206CDB2-19C1-11D1-89E0-00C04FD7A829} failed due to the following error: 800703fa Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703FA)

Comment: Pls follow offical doc to try, then if there is more information, you can update it in the post.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this problem, please follow official doc to try.

**Method 1**

Do not log on to the server for interactive sessions by using a service account.

**Method 2**

Disable the related Windows User Profile Service feature.

For more details, please read this article.

["800703fa Illegal operation attempted on a registry key" error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/administration/800703fa-illegal-operation-error)